# PHP send mail to multiple recipients without sharing email addresses

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send email to multiple recipients using PHP. My code is like this

```
<?php
foreach($subscribers as $subscriber){ 
$email[] = $subscriber['email'];
}
$emails = implode(',', $email);
$email_from = "email@example.com";
$subject = "My Subject";
    $full_name = 'Example Sender';
    $from_mail = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';
$email_text = file_get_contents('email.html');
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from_mail . "\r\n".
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
mail($emails, $subject, $email_text, $headers);
?>
```

I am able to send emails correctly. But it shows others email addresses in there email box and I don't want to share email addresses with each other. Please help how can I do this. I tried to send email inside the for each loop like this

```
<?php
    foreach($subscribers as $subscriber){ 
    $email = $subscriber['email'];
    $email_from = "email@example.com";
    $subject = "My Subject";
    $full_name = 'Example Sender';
    $from_mail = $full_name.'<'.$email_from.'>';
    $email_text = file_get_contents('email.html');
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from_mail . "\r\n".
               "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
               "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    mail($email, $subject, $email_text, $headers);
    }
?>
```

But it sends email to only the first email address inside loop. Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Mail hide other recipient addresses with multiple function calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998355/php-mail-hide-other-recipient-addresses-with-multiple-function-calls)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty string in the `$email` field and use bcc headers to add the mail addresses. bcc makes sure the receiver can't see the other email addresses.

```
$headers .= "Bcc:email@example.com" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Ok. So this should solve my problem  $headers .= 'BCC: '. implode(",", $email) . "\r\n";
mail(null, $subject, $email_text, $headers);